# How to access the locally built docker-image on the docker-swarm manager?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine, docker-image

While trying to build a service on **docker-machine** i got an error of **"image doesn't exist"** on that **docker-machine manager node**. As I checked the **docker images** command on the **manager node**, no image was there as expected. But on the root docker side I have those images. I want to access these images on the manager node. I've read few articles where it was mentioned that, maybe I've to upload that image on the docker hub then pull it from that hub. But I want to access it locally. Is there any way to do this as I'm newbie to docker.

This is the command what I tried on my manager machine:

> **docker@manager:~$ docker service create --name "api-client" -p 4200:4200 api_client**

This is my docker images output:

> **REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE**
>
> **api_client     latest              097b19c4deb8        27 hours ago        1.15GB**

But on my **docker@manager** terminal, my docker image folder is empty.

Comment: You properly need to put your image into a repository first. The repository is where each node will pull the image from before it execute. The repository can be either local or in the cloud. If you want a local repository, this is a good place to start https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

Comment: my image is already built and it is local repository. But I want to access it on the **docker-machine swarm**

Comment: Which repository do you run?. Can you show me the result of "docker images" ?

Comment: Edited. Do check @F.Madsen

Comment: That was what I suspected. "Docker images" shows what is in the local docker cache. That is NOT a repository, so you need to install a repository locally or get one in the cloud such as "docker HUB". the easiest is the cloud version, and it is free for one privat images and unlimited public images. I can create an "Answer" with the general steps you have to go thru if you want ?

Comment: got it. I've the idea of docker hub but i didn't know about the local repository. You can create the steps, it'll be beneficial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is no repository to hold the image. The repository needs to be pulled from to a repository to each node in the Swarm before it can execute. In general you need to do the following:

1. Setup a repository, if you want a local repository there is a guide [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/), but it will be some hassle to get it up and running i and "insecure http" version. An easier way is to get yourself a free [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) account and put your image there.
2. Tag your local image with the repository name. Howto is shown in the guide above.

> `docker tag <local image> <repository>/<image:tag>`

3. Login to the repository (if in cloud) and push your image to the repository

> `docker login`
>
> `docker push <repository>/<image>:<tag>`

4. To run the image (your command)

> ```
> docker service create --name "api-client" -p 4200:4200 <repository>/<image>:<tag>
> ```

Your can also try to pull an image into the local cache of a node using

> `docker pull <repository>/<image>:<tag>`